# AltBeacon Library shows beacons only first time and then stops showing them

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I am using `altbeacon` library for detecting `iBeacon`. It shows all beacons on first scanning then some beacons are missing out.

This is my situation:

- I have 7 beacons, on first scanning the app detecting all beacons.
- If I again try to scan for beacons it shows only 4.

How can I fix this? I am adding my code below.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);    
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
    backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);
    beaconManager.bind(this);

    return START_STICKY;
 }

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {  
    RangeNotifier rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier() {
           @Override
           public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                if (beacons.size() > 0)
                {
                    Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                    String beaconID = String.valueOf(firstBeacon.getId3());
                    Log.v("beacons",""+beaconID);
                }
             }
        };
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("buuid", Identifier.parse(buuid), null, null));
            beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
        }
      catch (RemoteException e) { }
    }
```

Comment: How was your 3rd and 4th scan? Your scanning device can lost signal, so you need to scan again, and get possibility of detection.

Comment: when i open my app for first time and scanned, all beacons where shown in the app.Then i closed my app and cleared from recent apps.Then again reopened it was showing only one 4. Is there any change i have to make in the code?

Comment: If there is only two beacons it is working fine,Now i tested with 3 beacons.When i restart the app after clearing from background apps it shows only 1 beacon out of three.

Comment: @davidgyoung  could you help ?

Comment: The code shown simply prints a log line indicating the first beacon seen.  I see no parts of the code that changes program output for the number of beacons seen.  What precisely about the program output is different from your expectations?

Comment: @davidgyoung  The output of the code is log line indicating detected beacon id. when i open my app for first time,it shown all beacon ids in log line .Then i closed my app and cleared from recent apps.Then again reopened .It doesnt print some beacon ids in log.That means app doesnt detect some beacons. This is my problem. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The code is currently printing out the third identifier of the first beacon seen:

```
if (beacons.size() > 0) {
   Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
   String beaconID = String.valueOf(firstBeacon.getId3());
   Log.v("beacons",""+beaconID);
}
```

It is NOT printing out a count of beacons seen.  If you want it to print out the count of beacons seen, do this.

```
Log.v("beacon count", ""+beacons.count);
```

**EDIT: ** Also, understand that if you only look at the *first* beacon when there are multiple around, it may not behave consistently due to indeterminate ordering of the detections.  You really need to see a list of all beacon ids detected, so use a loop like this:

```
Log.v("beacons", "Here are the beacons I see:");
for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
   String beaconID = String.valueOf(beacon.getId3());
   Log.v("beacons","beacon id: "+beaconID);
}
```

The above will print a list like this:

```
Here are the beacons I see:
3
4
5
```

The order of identifiers may be different from one run to a next, but the list of the identifiers should generally be the same as long as all the beacons remain around.

Comment: my problem is not about printing the count of beacon. The problem is ,I closed the app and cleared from recent apps. Then i reopen the app.Then the library is not detecting all beacons.It missess some of the beacon.

Comment: could you please help with this?